# How to show powershell input as part of output

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm trying to get the OS version of a selection of the computers on my domain. I created a powershell command that does this but it is missing the computer name on the output.

This is the command
`Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -Like "test"} | select "name" | foreach {$_.name} {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_.name} | Select-Object  Description, Caption,SevicePackMajorVersion | out-gridview`

I've tried adding addtional select-objects but they are all blank. I'm thinking this is because this wmiobject simply doesn't contain the machine name.

So my question is, as I'm piping in the name with `$_.name` is it possible it can be part of the output as well. I've tried using variations of `($_.name)` in the select-object command but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem` you can see the full list of properties available with the command `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | select-object *`.  Doing that would give you a table of properties and values.  The property that would probably be helpful to you is the `PSComputerName` property.

So something like this should include the details you want.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName . | select-object PSComputerName,Description,Caption,SevicePackMajorVersion
```

Comment: Wow that simple thank you very much. I also didn't realise you could use select-object * that would have been handy to know in the past.